# I'm new in Odoo anyone can help i want to disappear the tax from report if no tax in the order line else will dispaly tax column

Tags: xml, odoo

```
<template id="testReport" inherit_id="sale.report_saleorder_document">
    <t t-foreach="doc.order_line" t-as="line">
        <xpath expr="//th[@name='th_taxes']" position="replace">
            <th t-if="line.tax_id"></th>
        </xpath>
    </t>
</template>
```

inherited the sale report and do the condition if the tax_id is exist don't do anything else replace thing

Answer (score 0):

```xml
<template id="testReport" inherit_id="sale.report_saleorder_document">
    <t t-set="has_tax" t-value="doc.order_line.mapped('tax_id')"/>
    <t t-foreach="doc.order_line" t-as="line">
        <xpath expr="//th[@name='th_taxes']" position="replace">
            <th t-if="has_tax"></th>
        </xpath>
    </t>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, it stills the same after doing those changes,

Comment: This will be the case if atleast one of the lines has taxes, otherwise that header will be empty